# What is more productive in the OpenGL renderer loop: "if" operator or lambda?

Tags: java, android, functional-programming, opengl-es

When the rendering of the game is started, part of the algorithm changes (handling of the click on the screen).

There are two options.
1. Use the "if" operator:

```
public class Leve1 implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
  private boolean isLoadGame = false;
  public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
    ...
    isLoadGame = true; // game is now loaded
  }
  // this method is called often in the render loop
  public void setPassXY(float x, float y) {
    if (isLoadGame) {
      ... // perform algorithm 
    }
  }
}
```

2. Use the lambda (without "if"):

```
public class Leve1 implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
  // when the game is not loaded yet use the empty method body
  private PressXYInterface<Float, Float> pressXY = (pressX, pressY) -> {};
  public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
    ...
    pressXY = (passX, passY) -> { 
      ... // game is now loaded - add algorithm
    };
  }
  // this method is called often in the render loop
  public void setPassXY(float x, float y) {
    pressXY.invoke(x, y); // perform algorithm
  }
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface PressXYInterface<T, U> {
  void invoke(T x, U y);
}
```

Question: which approach is better to use in terms of performance?

Comment: Implement them both and let us know?

Comment: @NormadMaker Hello! If I will can measure performance). In general, this is a special case of the general question: what is faster in loops: lamda or "if" operator?

Comment: In your example I think there must be a third way: to not update until the game is loaded, but I can't try this now and I just don't know.

Comment: @NomadMaker You see, the method setPassXY() is called from the outside (from a class that extends GLSurfaceView), so it can be called before the game loads.

Comment: What about having one class set things up, and the game object being started only after everything has already been loaded?

Comment: @NomadMaker Maybe you're right. But here was used a template Java SDK for OpenGL that I know: in game activity create an instance of GLSurfaceView that launches the render object GLSurfaceView.Renderer in another thread. Along with this, event methods are defined in the class GLSurfaceView, therefore they can be called before initialized of game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - There is not a single correct answer.  It depends on lots of factors.  Benchmarking your *real* application is the only way to get a reliable answer.

---

Here are some of the issues:

On the one hand, the version using lambdas saves an `if` statement.

On the other hand, the version using the method call can potentially be inlined by the JIT compiler.  (These lambda calls cannot be inlined because at different points in time the call site may be calling different lambdas.)

On the other hand, if `// perform algorithm` is complicated enough, it will be too big to inline.

On the other hand, if the `algorithm` is too big to inline, *perhaps* the cost of the `if` test will be insignificant.

On the other hand, the `if` test may be less expensive than you imagine.  For example:

- If the code is JIT compiled after switching to `isLoadGame == true` state, then the stats may tell the JIT compiler to optimize for the case where the the test succeeds.
- (Hardware) branch prediction may adjust to the modal behavior of that test.

On the other hand, it is not clear to me which versions need to make simple calls or virtual calls.  Or whether the JIT compiler *could* optimize the virtual calls. I simply don't know.  (An examination of the bytecodes would give a partial answer.)

Then there are the issues of different JIT compiler versions, different hardware ISA, different hardware implementations.

In short, there are too many factors to predict which approach will perform better in reality.

This also means that micro-benchmarking is not likely to be helpful.  Many of the above factors will depend critically on the real application code and the way that the application starts up.  You will need to benchmark the real application to get meaningful results.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! By the way, measurements of time showed approximately the same results. There are no particular benefit to using lambdas in this case.